# MVC controller parameter found null

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

When i upload file from index the Create controller parameter can found null why?
I am using to db model is 'File' and model class is 'MyfileModel'

```
  public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase filesBase)
    {         
         try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Files.Add(new File()
                {
                    FileName = Path.GetFileName(filesBase.FileName)
                });
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            var error = "Sorry not save";
        }
        return Content("");
    }



@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype =    "multipart/form-data"}))
{
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload"/> 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input must have name "fileBase". Or change the name of the input parameter in your action to "file".

Comment: Thank you matko,it works.
if i read fiile name from database how can i do that?

Comment: Do you need to assign the name to your File from Database?

Comment: I think that assigning form field names according to something stored in database is not a good practice. Form fields should be generated for the properties of your model/viewmodel. You have CreateModel, with property File, so the name of the field should be File.

Comment: Yes,i use viewmodel that i mentioned which name is MyfileModel and i need the file name and also display the file by iframe.

Comment: If the name attribute of the form input field will be dynamic, you will not be able to get the posted file as an input parameter in your action, because the name of the input parameter in your action is once written in your code (HttpPostedFileBase *file*). Than you will have to process *Request.Files* collection to find the right posted file, which far more worse approach.

Comment: Now how should i do that to get all files from database?

Comment: I did this to get file name from database.It is the normal way to get this.
`     public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var file = db.Files.ToList();
            List<string> items = new List<string>();
            foreach (var files in file)
            {
                items.Add(files.FileName);
            }
            return View(items);
        }
`

Comment: Input element with type file, is used for file uploading.

Answer (score 0):

See how i am doing to achieve the same,

**Controller Code:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult File()
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {                
            var file = Request.Files[0];
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**In View File:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("File", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

   <div class="form-group">
        <input name="file" type="file" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: It's not compulsory to add the `HttpPostedFileBase` in the Action.